# Move forward continously with a Character Controller?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

My question sums up what I'm trying to do.

I searched the internet and everyone keeps giving me the usual `transform.Translate` answer which doesn't work for me because I need the physics and collisions not just move the character forward.

I know how to do this with a `rigidbody` but my character keeps rolling, something I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you character rolls, you could freeze some rotation constraints on the rigidbody.

Anyway here's something from the scripting reference for character controllers: https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html

From it, I guess you can adjust for what you need.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the constraints. This did solve my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CharacterController and use its Move and SimpleMove functions. See the default character package to learn more about it, and, you could use the character motor script from that package as well.

Comment: Hi, I used the Move and SimpleMove functions with the Character Controller but I couldn't figure it out how to continuously make my character move forward. Can you specify how should I use the Character Motor script because everything in the script is wired with Jumping.

Thanks!

Comment: The character motor script is really simple. All you need to do is to give it a direction in which to move, and it'll move in that direction. If you don't want jumping, you can disable it. Also, to use SimpleMove, just give it a velocity each frame (in update()) and it'll keep moving forward. Don't use rigidbodies for character movement unless your character is physical (say, a ball). It'll cause problems later on.

Answer (score 0):

Well First Add The Character Controller component create a new script called Move then open it and copy and paste this code

```
  #pragma strict

function Update () {
var Controller : CharacterController = GetComponent(CharacterController);
var forward : Vector3 = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
Controller.SimpleMove(forward);
}
```

After that add the script to your player object then you are done:)